# PHP: Simple HTML DOM - parsing problem with missing </TR> tag

Tags: php

I am parsing a local file that is extracted from a system as a .htm file, I am therefore using Simple HTML DOM.

The file has only a single table and I basically want to capture each row in the table and save it as regular .csv file.

It would all work wonderfully except for the fact that the html file has a missing `</TR>` tag at the end of the first row (in every case). This means that my code captures the first `$tr` as the whole table instead of just the col name headers.

There are some pre-requisites to fixing this:-

The extracted .htm file cannot be manually edited in any way.
The first row cannot be counted in any way as columns may change (in order and number).
The first cell of the second row will be a 0 a lot of the time, but not always.

Here is the html (as a subset; original extract is 30,000+ rows)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<META name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 11.00.10570.1001"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Monthly Report</H1><BR><BR><BR>
<P>               Reporting Level : Ledger<BR>             Reporting Context :
2466<BR>                  Company Name : topcage<BR>         Set of Books Currency :
2466<BR>                 Register Type : All<BR>                 Summary Level :
Transaction Distribution Level<BR>                       Product : All<BR>
<P>
<TABLE border="1">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD><B>Tax Amt</B></TD>
    <TD><B>Tax Amt Funcl Curr</B></TD>
    <TD><B>Taxable Amt</B></TD>
    <TD><B>Taxable Amt Funcl Curr</B></TD>
    <TD><B>Total Entered Amount</B></TD>
    <TD><B>Trx Line Class</B></TD>
  <TR>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>179</TD>
    <TD>179</TD>
    <TD>179</TD>
    <TD>INVOICE</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>177</TD>
    <TD>177</TD>
    <TD>177</TD>
    <TD>INVOICE</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>262.5</TD>
    <TD>262.5</TD>
    <TD>262.5</TD>
    <TD>INVOICE</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD align="LEFT" colspan="6"><B>Report Count</B></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD>3</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR>*** End of Report *** </P></BODY></HTML>
```

Here is my code:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.htm');
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");

    foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr)
    {
        $row = array();
        foreach($tr->find('td') as $td)
        {
          $row[] = $td->innertext;
        }
        fwrite($myfile, implode($row, ",") . "\n");

    }
     fclose($myfile);
```

Here is the content of the file that is generated:-

```
<b>Tax Amt</b>,<b>Tax Amt Funcl Curr</b>,<b>Taxable Amt</b>,<b>Taxable Amt Funcl Curr</b>,<b>Total Entered Amount</b>,<b>Trx Line Class</b>,0,0,179,179,179,INVOICE,0,0,177,177,177,INVOICE,0,0,262.5,262.5,262.5,INVOICE,<b>Report Count</b>,,,,,,3
0,0,179,179,179,INVOICE
0,0,177,177,177,INVOICE
0,0,262.5,262.5,262.5,INVOICE
<b>Report Count</b>
,,,,,3
```

Comment: You can replace `</TD>(spaces/newlines)<TR>` with `</TD></TR><TR>` for example and parse as usual.

Comment: If you mean in the original .htm file, as per the pre-requisites I stated, the original extracted file cannot be edited; it has to be a fully automated parse process.

Comment: Not in original file, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('file.htm');
$pattern = '/<\/TD>(\s*)<TR>/i';
$replacement = '</TD></TR><TR>';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
$html = str_get_html($html);
```

instead of:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.htm');
```

this way you get the file contents and replace what you want before processing it.

Comment: I've checked the regex here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5e4ff4a304534285a311b0aa5bab87c15b977c2

Comment: the regex replacement works great except for the fact that the `$html = str_get_html($html);` returns `$html` as a boolean rather than an object, thus causing it to error out.

Having a play with it to see what is pertaining.

Comment: This can be because the html string is too large and simple_html_dom has a maximum limit that can parse. In this case it will return false. Try increasing the limit with something like: `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10000000);` at the top of your php script